# RecyclerView refreshes items only when scrolling down and up

Tags: android, refresh, android-recyclerview

I am making a simple recyclerview with Movie items. When I try adding new items they won't display in the recyclerview right away. For some reason I have to scroll down so the first item is gone, and then up again for the new item to be displayed (it's added at index 0).

The adapter:

```
public class MovieCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieCardAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {
List<Movie> movieList;

public MovieCardAdapter(final List<Movie> movieList) {
    this.movieList = movieList;
}

public void addItem(int position, final Movie movie){
    movieList.add(position,movie);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void removeItem(final Movie movie){
    final int indexOf = movieList.indexOf(movie);
    movieList.remove(movie);
    notifyItemRemoved(indexOf);
}

public void updateItems(final List<Movie> items){
    movieList = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.movie_row, viewGroup, false);

    return new MovieViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MovieViewHolder movieViewHolder, final int i) {
    final Movie movie = movieList.get(i);

    String posterUrl = "";
    final int posterHeight = 240;
    if (!isEmpty(movie.getImdb_id())) {
        posterUrl = "http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=" + movie.getImdb_id() + "&apikey="+apiKey+"&h=" + posterHeight;
    } else if (!isEmpty(movie.getPoster())) {
        posterUrl = movie.getPoster();
    }
    if (!isEmpty(posterUrl)) {
        Picasso.with(movieViewHolder.context)
                .load(posterUrl)
                .resize(220, 354)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(movieViewHolder.poster);
    }

    movieViewHolder.title.setText(movie.getTittel());
    movieViewHolder.format.setText(movie.getFormat());

    if (movie.getRuntime().isEmpty() || movie.getRuntime().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
        movieViewHolder.runtime.setText("");
    }else{
        movieViewHolder.runtime.setText(movie.getRuntime()+" mins");
    }

    if (!movie.getTagline().isEmpty()) {
        movieViewHolder.tagline.setText(movie.getTagline());
    } else if (!movie.getPlot().isEmpty()) {
        movieViewHolder.tagline.setText(movie.getPlot());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieList.size();
}

public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected Context context;
    protected LinearLayout movieRowLinearLayout;
    protected ImageView poster;
    protected TextView title;
    protected TextView runtime;
    protected TextView tagline;
    protected TextView format;

    public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        movieRowLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.movieRowLinearLayout);
        poster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.poster);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        runtime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.runtime);
        tagline = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tagline);
        format = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.format);
    }
}
```

}

Initializing the adapter:

```
adapter = new MovieCardAdapter(MovieList.movies);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Adding a sample movie:

```
if (id == R.id.add_movie) {
        final Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTittel("0TEST");
        movie.setFormat("HD-DVD");

        MovieList.sortMoviesByTitle();
        adapter.addItem(MovieList.movies.indexOf(movie), movie);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_logOut) {
        logOut(this);
    }
```

Sry bad english, hope someone understands and know what the problem might be.
I have tried adding from runOnUiThread([...]), but same result.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because position 0 is above the current visible screen.
Until transcript mode is implemented, when you are adding an item to position `N`, try calling `scrollToPosition(N)` if `LinearLayoutManager#findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` returns `N`.

Also, don't make the position parameter `final` in your `onBindViewHolder` method. Instead, use `ViewHolder.getPosition()` if you need it in a callback. When position of the item changes, you will not receive an onBind call unless the item itself is invalidated.

**Update**

Also your update logic is not correct because you are not clearing values in views.

```
if (!movie.getTagline().isEmpty()) {
    movieViewHolder.tagline.setText(movie.getTagline());
} else if (!movie.getPlot().isEmpty()) {
    movieViewHolder.tagline.setText(movie.getPlot());
} else {
    movieViewHolder.tagline.setText(null);
}
```

Same for the poster URL.

Comment: Tried it, but the added item is not "on top" of the recyclerView. It is first when the first items is "recycled" that it gets visible. I have tried debugging, and sees that the item is added to the list in the adapter.

Comment: Hmm, updated the answer w/ one more problem in the code. 
If it is still broken, feel free to send me an app or create a bug report on b.android.com with a sample app.

Comment: I have the project open av https://github.com/olavbg/MyMoovs
But it Work In Progress, with many things that could/should be better.

Comment: Ups, posted the wrong github link, this is the correct one: https://github.com/olavbg/Material-Design-Test-App

Comment: This error ocurred from origins of android .... recycleview and listview .... (Android have support ? about this position that you called "N" ?)

Answer (score 1):

`layoutManager.scrollToPosition` didn't solve the problem for me.

Not a definitive solution, but the following line did the trick in my case:

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, 0);
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this solved the problem to me

```
layoutManager.scrollToPosition
```