# RecyclerView change wrong value's on scroll up / down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

previously i used a listview and a custom adapter for the listview.
all worked fine, except when i scroll up and down the data changed (e.g i've an if statement i the adapter to change the bg color of the listview item. when i scroll up and down the color changed wrong, on the first load and scroll all was fine!)

i solved this problem for the listview by resetting the view always to null in the getView method in my adapter.

```
v = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendlv, null);
```

now i switched to RecyclerView and there i've the same issue but i've no idea to solve this issue..

thanks!

Comment: it could be that if you not set the correct dynamic property of the `onBindViewHolder`. For example, you change the background in one case but you will have to change back in the `else` state. Plz post your full adapter class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once you set the property, it is persistent for that item. When you scroll, that view disappears from the screen and that same item layout is used again for next item. So you need to write else condition to reset the old properties.

So, you should add `else` statement to all your `if` statements as illustrated in following example

```
if (condition) {
    change bg color to new color
}
else {
    change bg color to old color
}
```

Comment: this solved the issue but i dont undestand why... may i ask you to explain!

Comment: sorry, it works! i've edit my comment above. but i dont understand why i works now. if i change the color only when condition is x

Comment: It works because 
Once you set the property it persistent for that Item, once you scroll and that view is disappears from screen that same row item layout use again for next item so you need to write else condition for next use

Comment: Works ? read other post please .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460164/recyclerview-refreshes-items-only-when-scrolling-down-and-up // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236818/android-development-recycleview-listview-always-wrong-position-refresh-up-d

Comment: @Gaurav I may have a similar problem here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43531900/android-how-to-fix-recyclerview-onbindviewholder.  I have added and ELSE statement and am still getting an error.  I would appreciate if you could provide any thoughts or ideas on how to fix.

Comment: @AJW The specified question is removed or deleted